YA/children's TV series/movie from the late 90s/early 00s where a group of kids have to find the pieces of a broken magic crystal
All I can remember is that the crystal/stone was see-through and colorless, circular in shape, but flat (so it wasn't an orb) with some kind of pattern in the middle (maybe a tree, or some other nature-related motif). It got broken up into several pieces and a group of kids had to find the broken shards scattered around the world to reassemble it on a stone table or a pillar-like holder thing.
I saw it sometime in the early 2000s, so it could be from then or even from the late '90s. It was a live-action series with human actors, so not Inuyasha or The Dark Crystal.

Was this set on modern day Earth? And how did the kids travel around the world?

I don't remember clearly, but I think it was set in a fantasy world, but the kids were probably from our world. I don't remember the latter, unfortunately. I have only seen 1 episode (if it was even a series, but I think it was) and I was very little.

Possibly season 2 of Into The Labyrinth.

The series was based around a struggle between two timeless, feuding sorcerers - the noble Rothgo (Ron Moody) and the evil Belor (Pamela Salem). Each aimed to obtain possession of the Nidus, a magical object of limitless power. ...The first series followed a group of modern-day children (Phil, Helen and Terry) who find Rothgo, almost lifeless, in a labyrinthine cave. Rothgo sends the children through different periods of time to search for the Nidus, which is disguised as a different object in each time period and can only be seen in reflection.
...
In the second series, Belor returns with her own power source, the Albedo, with which she hopes to destroy Rothgo and take possession of the Nidus. However, during their battle, the two power sources collide leaving the Albedo destroyed and the Nidus split into five segments which scatter throughout time and space. As before, Rothgo enlists the help of Phil, Terry and Helen to retrieve the fragments which are again disguised as objects and can only be seen in reflection.

Entire run of the show available on youtube.
